# Keeping color of shapefile constant in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, symbology, arcgis-9.3

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 when I use a color for the shapefile it changes everytime when I close and open ArcMap.

How I can constantly keep the color of the shapefile that I work with?

Answer (score 9):

Three options I can think of:

1. [Save your map document](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Saving_a_map_and_exiting_ArcMap) and [open](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Opening_a_map) it when you subsequently want to work with the shapefile. This should be obvious so perhaps you have not explained why this is not working for you.
2. Save the layer to a [layer file](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=Saving_a_layer_to_disk) and load that instead of the shapefile
3. Load the shapefile into a [geodatabase](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_the_geodatabase) and set up a [cartographic representation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_representations) on it

Comment: Blah has covered all the sensible options.  For the sake of completeness, you could also create a colour code look-up-table.  This is very old-school I know but you can then distribute this with your data so the same colours can be used in a different GIS other than Arc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to save your work in .mxd (Go to File--Save as and the save all your data in .mxd format. Next time when you open the .mxd it gives you same color )

Link :http://prod.library.utoronto.ca/maplib/docs/ArcGISmxdhelp.pdf (instead as save as copy click on save as)

Try this and let us know.. thank you..